# Teradata not responding in Windows Server 2012

Tags: odbc, teradata, windows-server-2012, windows-server, teradata-sql-assistant

I am trying to install Teradata connection in a virtual machine of Windows Server 2012.
I tried multiple times but I still got the timed out error: No response received when attempting to connect the Teradata error.

I tried connecting through SQL assistant and python teradata module. Below is what I have tried based on resolutions found on web search and none of them works
1. Close the firewall
2. Change the odbcLibPath (in Python)
3. Reinstall .NET framework
4. Extend the time awaiting for response
5. Seeking resolutions around odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini but for Windows specifically, I can not find any resolution.

I have also not be able to find much difference between the configuration on the virtual machine and that on my local desktop which works well.

I felt I have run out of possible solutions at the moment. Appreciate any help in this.

Comment: This sounds like a networking issue not a teradata or teradata client issue. Can you ping the teradata server? If so, try to netcat or telnet on port 1025 to your server from that machine. If you hit a wall, then you know that 1025 isn't connecting through your network.

Comment: @JNevill. Thanks for the reply.  I think I can ping the server but 1025 is not connecting through the network.I pinged the server and got "reply from [an ip address].......”. Then I telnet the server on port 1025.It starts "Connecting to  [host]" and no other response so far. Is there anything I can do as an user? Really appreciate your further input. I am new to this and sorry if the question is stupid.

Comment: As a user, probably not. You need to hit up your networking folks. Give them the IP you are trying to connect from, the IP of the server and the port and they can open it up for you.